# Does SCO Unix 7.1.4 come with Python installed?

Tags: python, sco-unix

Does SCO Unix 7.1.4 come with Python installed? I searched on Google but couldn't find any clue.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably included in UnixWare 7.1.4. but if not, it is available from [SCO Skunkware](http://www.sco.com/skunkware/devtools/index.html#python) but is unlikely to be the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely.  It may be available as contributed software, though.  If it isn't in the contributed software you will have to install it from the source tree.